# While clicking the showMore button, it dynamically load json list from file

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, mustache

I am working on a dropwizard-Java project.

I need to fetch and display first 10 elements from json list in mustache view.

If I click show more link, needed to fetch next 10 elements from list and display them.

I have coded till displaying all the elements. But I need to display via show more link.

Comment: Add a lot more details, code snippets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call on show more link. Load first 10 elements. When someone clicks show more get 10 elements after first 10 and display and so on.

Comment: If you don't have huge list of elements and these elements nested too much. You can keep list front end only and display elements on "More" click.

Comment: I have huge list of data for processing..I am not aware of ajax..will try it